# Error code 89710016 with Resharper Unit testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, resharper

During a long, quite fruitful debugging session, out of the blue I received the following error message when running a NUnit test as debugger. The unit test uses web services to various endpoints, though I doubt that is relevant.

[image]

I use R# 8.2.1, but after weird errors like these, I guess it is time to update. Posting it here for reference, in case others have it too or, better yet, in case someone has found a solution to the problem other than restarting Visual Studio (which is my current *"solution"*).

PS: this is an old, not migrated project, hence VS 2010 in the tags. I have not seen this error with VS2012 or VS2013 yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case:
VS 2015 Enterprise Update 2
Resharper 9.2

Same issue. After some googling and trying dummy project what worked for me was setting test project to compile for x86. Then no error popup. For us it was OK since we agreed to have debug working in x86 and making releases in x64.
Maybe this will help.

Comment: Had the same issue with a similar Dev setup - changing the test applications and any dependent assembly to 'Any CPU' did the trick.

Comment: This answer, and @JK's comment suggest that the error message is caused by a misconfiguration of image formats between dlls (i.e. x86 calling x64 or vv). I haven't seen the error anymore, but will accept this as a good potential answer, unless somebody else comes by with more insight.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution to change to x86 did not work for me.

What worked was using Managed Compatibility Code in VS (2017) : Tools-> Options -> Debugging -> General -> checking Use Managed Compatibility Mode.